# Blade template vs plain php in Laravel

Tags: php, parsing, laravel-4, laravel-blade

As I understand, `Blade` is simply `regex` parser, which will translate any `Blade` construction into `PHP` code, and then generate plain `HTML` from that `PHP`. Seems like this process makes loading files with `Blade` templates slower (because of the extra step `Blade` -> `PHP`). If so, why do I want to use `Blade` at all? Just because of the elegant syntax or because `Blade` files are stored in `cache`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'd use Blade because you want to use Blade. Like you've said it has a much nicer syntax and once you know its simple syntax it's very quick to use.

Regular PHP:

```
<?php if ($user->isLogged()): ?>
    Welcome back, <strong><?= $user->name; ?></strong>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Blade:

```
@if ($user->isLogged())
    Welcome back, <strong>{{ $user->name }}</strong>
@endif
```

Of course that's just a basic control structure. Blade has built in templating support as well.

### Speed

There should be virtually no speed difference between the two as on the first load Laravel will compile any views that have changed into their PHP equivalent. Subsequent page loads will use this compiled file instead (they are stored at `app/storage/views`).

I guess the only extra overhead would be the initial check to see if the view has been compiled yet. Bugger all though.

Comment: This is valid PHP too:
<?php if ($user->isLogged()) { ?>
    Welcome back, <strong><?= $user->name ?></strong>
<?php } ?>

Comment: You've missed one of the most important reasons to use a tempting language on the web today, which is **auto-escaping**. In your example, echoing the username in PHP is susceptible to XSS, whereas outputting via the tempting language will automatically escape the string. This is a good reason to use any tempting language, Blade included, which doesn't veer into arguing about personal taste.

Comment: @gpmcadam I know you meant templating but on some level the fact you made the typo 3 times is making me wonder.